# In Ubuntu, how do I find all photos of the Raw format taken after Jan 1, 2015, and if they total less than 30G, put them on an external drive?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

This question has three parts:

1. How do I find all RAW format photos.

   I assume I am going to use the find command.  I have used find successfully exactly once:

   ```
   find . -name creek.jpg
   ```

   to find creek.jpg in the current folder.  How do I search by date?  The man page has a list of 'primaries' that allow you to tell find to search by things like date, and it's like reading a foreign language: I can't understand the man page.  Also, I assume that find uses the date the photo was uploaded to the system, and not the date in the metadata of the picture itself.
2. How do I keep a running total of how big these files are?

   I have no idea which shell command to use.  Should I do it the hacky way and copy the photos into a folder and simply use a shell command to find out how big the folder is?  I'm leary of doing that, because I am doing support for a photographer who takes a LOT of raw photos, and I don't want to run her computer out of memory by duplicating raw photos.
3. I assume putting them on an external drive is as simple as using the cp command.

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: There are lots and lots of examples out there of `find` command syntax.  Just searching for `linux find by date` turns up a number of useful looking results.  What have you tried so far?  What didn't work?

Comment: "Linux find syntax" gives me the man page and a bunch of tutorials written by people who use the same terms as the man page.  Since I do not understand the man page, I do not understand the tutorials.  For example, here is the man page's definition of find. In italics are words I do not understand.   The _find_ _utility_ _recursively_ descends the _directory_ _tree_ for each _path_ listed, _evaluating_ an _expression_ (_composed_ of the _primaries_ and _operands_ listed below) in terms of each _file_ in the _tree._)  I hope this shows the extent of my difficulty.

Comment: Right now I am doing a bunch of command line tests on various examples to see how they work.  Since I do not really get what find is doing, this is a brute-force approach and I was hoping stack overflow could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bunch of questions to ask and answers to find before you can even get started.

First, you need to know **WHERE** the files are stored because that is the first parameter for `find`, e.g.

```
find $HOME ...
```

or

```
find "/mnt/EXTERNAL DRIVE" ...
```

Second, you need to know the extension of the RAW files the camera creates, it may be `.CR2` on a Canon or `.TIF` or `.DNG` or `.NEF` on a Nikon, or `.mrw` on a Minolta. Then you can get the second parameter for `find`:

```
find $HOME -iname "*.NEF"
```

Good, now you can get a list of the files. But you want to know when they were shot. Unfortunately, Ubuntu isn't going to know that, on its own, though it will know when files were created, so you may find it better to let Ubuntu weed out old files so you don't have to pass them to the next step which will be slower. So, how do we get Ubuntu to only find files newer than 1 Jan 2015 (since files put on disk before then were presumably not shot since January 2015).

Well, one way would be to create a file dated 1 January 2015, and then to tell `find` to only find newer files. So, let's try that:

```
# Create file with earliest date we want to find - i.e. 1 Jan 2015
touch -t 201501010000 earliest
```

Now add an extra parameter to `find` like this:

```
find $HOME -iname "*.CR2" -newer earliest
```

Next, if you want the actual shooting date, you will need to install **ImageMagick**, or `ufraw` or `dcraw` or somesuch to parse your raw files and get the date. Let's say you write a script called `CheckIfFileIsNew` and make it executable with

```
chmod +x CheckIfFileIsNew
```

then you will be able to run that script for all the files:

```
find $HOME -iname "*.cr2" -exec CheckIfFileIsNew {} \;
```

Then you need to learn how to `grep` the date out of a raw file. Then you need to learn how to run `stat` on a file to find its size. Then you need to learn some `awk` to total up all the file sizes to see if they exceed 30GB, then you can decide if you want to copy the files to the new place and if you do, you can replace the `exec` in the original `find` command with a `cp` command.

```
find $HOME -iname "*.cr2" -exec CheckIfFileIsNew {} \; | awk '{total+=$0} END{print $total}'
```

Your script `CXheckIfFileIsNew` will look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(identify -verbose "$1" | grep "dng:Timestamp")

# Work out of date is 2015 or 2016
# If date is 2015 or 2016; call `stat` to get the file size, print file size
# Output the size, in bytes, of the filename we were given as parameter
stat -c%s "$1"
```

Note that the `identify` command above may be pretty slow if you have a hi-res camera. You could try a command like `strings` on a couple of your RAW files to see if you can find the date in there that way and it will be miles faster:

```
strings SomeFile.RAW | grep -i date
```

Comment: Excellent! I want to specifically thank you for taking the time to  give me all of these examples and keywords.  The examples will help me in my tests, and the keywords will definately improve my odds of googling the right answers.  You are definitely right in that I have a lot of questions to to ask before I can build this script.

Comment: Good luck with your project!